How to group a certain number of records into 1 report?
Sorry for my bad English.
I am not much familiar with Crystal Reports. I facing one issue regarding Grouping in Crystal report.
I am creating an Purchase Order using Crystal Reports and requirement is below:

Each report has an autonumbering number.
Each Report is grouped by VendorID
Each Report has maximum 12 records.
So when we purchase from 1 Vendor and the number of the products is bigger than 12, we will have different reports and different autonumbering
For example:
Order to an Vendor A, 25 products are ordered.
So we will have 2 reports with 12 products, numbering is (PO01,PO02)
and 1 with 1 product, numbering is (PO03).
I dont know how to group a certain number of records into 1 report.
Can some one help me how do I do this kind of Stuff.

I grouped them by Vendor ID but dont know how to group a certain number of records into 1 report.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

See if this link helps.  It wouldn't hurt to read all of the suggested answers because there are multiple ways to achieve the result you desire.  Ideally, this is best done in the SQL that selects the data from the database, but if you aren't able to do this, the answer John Price provided would work, but its going to have some performance issues if the dataset is very large because it doesn't stop the data from being selected, it just discards data you don't want displayed after its selected, which is inefficient.
